# How to fix background go black when pop up is open in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

I'm trying to open a warning popup when ever a user go to my details screen and I did it like this under my builder but some reason the I only can see the warning dialog but not the details page anymore.

```
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBarWidget(
          appBar: AppBar(),
          showReorder: false,
        ),
        body: BaseView<CardViewModel>(
          onDeactivate: (model) {},
          onDispose: (model) {},
          onModelReady: (model) {
            model.getCard();
          },
          builder: (context, model, child) {
            WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
              setState(() {
                isLargeScreen = false;
                if (model.cards.current != true) {
                  if (model.cards.alreadyShow == false) {
                    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                      staticwarningDialog(context);         // I'm opening this dialog
                    });
                  }
                }
              });
            });
            return _body(model, height, width, context, widget.cardName);
          },
        ));
```

Currently it look like this
[image]

and it supposed too look like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

how you are showing and creating your dialog?

in your examples you are creating like a cards but not dialogs, to show dialogs you need call `showDialog`

[image: example, my dialog code]

[image: example, how i show my dialog]